# Remove parent object if nested object has a specific property as false on all nested objects

Tags: arrays, angular, object

Basically I have an array of objects as follows,

[image]

The blue circles are showing the property of the object that I need to check.

If all of the items in the options property has a model of "false", I want to delete the whole object from the array.

And if there are ture and false mixed ones, I want to only keep the ones that has true.

Any idea how to do this?

So basically because

```
TheArray[1].options['key1'].model = true;
```

I want to keep it all.

But because

```
TheArray[2].options['key1'].model = false;
TheArray[2].options['key2'].model = false;
```

I want to delete the whole `TheArray[2]`

if `TheArray[2]` was like below;

```
TheArray[2].options['key1'].model = true;
TheArray[2].options['key2'].model = false;
```

I would like to keep only `TheArray[2].options['key1'];`

Also I'm using angular 4 to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about browse the entire objects and keep the one which are fine?

```
for (var i = 0; i < TheArray.length; i++) {
  let checked = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < TheArray[i].options.length; j++) {
    let _this = TheArray[i].options[j]
    if ( _this.model ) {
      checked = true
      break
    }
  }
  if (!checked){
    // remove it
  }
}
```

This is not a complete answer. I mean, this algo doesn't remove the one which are false, but just remove the break part, add an `else` statement and remove it in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't really what I need. I don't want to use for loops tho, forEach is better for this case since I'll have to pass the data once it's finished to another function and for loops don't do that, they just start and go to the next line weather it's finished or not but i need it to wait for the loop to finish before passing it to another function

Comment: Totally false... You can break the whole thing or return the function inside a for loop what you can't do with .forEach()

Comment: you didn't even understand me

Comment: `I'll have to pass the data once it's finished to another function and for loops don't do that` this is false tho